# Java: my code is shown as a text file .. not as in a java format

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse (Indigo - version 3.7.2) from my local machine into a VM (Linux Ubuntu), and I managed to run subclipse to connect to the repository and pull my project(with all the code files inside the source folder).

now I am able to see my project and open my files, nonetheless my code is just a bunch of "normal text" lines.. when I try to check the Editor, it is a Text Editor and there is no Java editor available

what is missing .. here is a screen shot 
[image]

Comment: check to see if your folder is a source folder

Comment: @Jyro117: thanks for your reply .. if you mean the location where my file are located inside  my project then yes .. they are all inside the source folder .. otherwise:  how to do the check ?..

Comment: Try right-mouse-clicking on a ".java" file >> Open-With >> Java Editor.  If that doesn't work, you may have downloaded the wrong Eclipse bundle.  I recommend downloading the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" version.

Comment: If @Jyro117 is correct, you can add source folders with Eclipse's New Source Folder Wizard, documented [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-wizard-source-folder.htm)

Comment: I'm referring to something slightly different, it sometimes might be a plain folder (this happens occasionally with source control). You should see a package icon on the folder in package/project explorer. If you right-click the folder and go to Build Path, if it has "Use as Source Folder" press it to convert a plain folder to a source folder.

Comment: @MikeClark: I don't see the Java Editor within the Open-With options .. what does that mean ? .. and since I don't have the Java Editor, then I think I have to download "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"..  can you please put a link for a tutorial or a guidance

Comment: It would greatly help if you added a screenshot of what your eclipse currently looks like.

Comment: Can't do an exact link since it varies by platform.  Which file did you download before?  Get one that includes the Java tools from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2 or http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr2 .

Comment: @Jyro117: check my updated screenshot

Comment: Looks like your project isn't a java project. Can you pick that option when you create a new project?

Comment: @Jyro117: as you can see, there is also no package icon, is just folders and files

Comment: @flup: in fact no I can't

Comment: @Jyro117: there is no "Use as Source Folder" option

Comment: `Window > Open Perspective > Other > Java` then  `File > New > Project... > Java`.  If you don't have these menu options, download **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** or **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** @ http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps you are opening your Java file in a text editor.  To fix:

1. Select the file
2. Right-click -> Open With -> Java Editor

Comment: @AndrewEsenberg: it is writing to a Text Editor, basically because there is no Java Editor .. so what to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Get a version of Eclipse that includes the Java developer tools, for example

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr2

See http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ for a complete list of all flavors you can choose from.

Answer (score 1):

You can change a normal eclipse project to a Java project as suggested here:

Under Project Properties -> Project Facets -> Convert to faceted form... you can select Java - this will add the Java functionalities to your project. There you can also add other facets like Dynamic Web Module if necessary.